# WS2811 flicker to random colors when trying to turn them all off in a 3x3 array

Tags: fpga, c++, ws2811

I am trying to do more, but for starters, I am trying to write code to turn all of my WS2811 off that exist in a 3x3 array. Currently, when I run my Arduino project, they are flickering from red, to green, to blue like crazy. Only one of them, the middle one, is staying blue.

I am wondering if anyone with any experience working with the ws2811 could pinpoint the exact issue with just knowing this information. I know my code is correct to turn off the lights, since it is very simple, but I am not sure how to trouble shoot this issue.

Here is the code I am working with:

```
/**********************************************************************
 file: main_ws2812_basic.cpp - basic ws2812 test

 Copyright (C) 2018 p. chu

 This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 (at your option) any later version.

 This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 GNU General Public License for more details.

 You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 along with this program.  If not, see <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 **********************************************************************/
/*****************************************************************//**
 * @note neo8 is an 8-led strip
 * @note ws2812 is very bright (25% power is enough)
 * @note ws2812 specifies 5-V control signal
 ********************************************************************/

#include "de10_baseline.h"
#include "ws2812_core.h"
Ws2812Core light_matrix(get_slot_addr(BRIDGE_BASE,14),3,3);
int main() {


   int i = 0;
   int j = 0;

   for(i = 0; i<3; i++){
       for(j=0; j<3; j++){
           light_matrix.wr_pix(i,j,0x000000);
       }
   }
   while (1) {

          light_matrix.wr_pix(0,0,0x000000); 
          light_matrix.wr_pix(0,1,0x000000); 
          light_matrix.wr_pix(0,2,0x000000); 
          light_matrix.wr_pix(1,0,0x000000);
          light_matrix.wr_pix(1,1,0x000000); 
          light_matrix.wr_pix(1,2,0x000000);
          light_matrix.wr_pix(2,0,0x000000); 
          light_matrix.wr_pix(2,1,0x000000);
          light_matrix.wr_pix(2,2,0x000000);
     // sleep_ms(2000);
   }//while
}//main
```

And here is my circuitry: The first three wires are my voltage, ground, and data wire. (From right to left)

[image]

Comment: I don't have a certain answer, but perhaps the signal integrity is being impacted by some detail in your construction method. When I was wiring thousands of these up and in long strings, I had to use line drivers and series resistors to drive them hard but without any ringing. I believe this page could be helpful to you: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-neopixel-uberguide/best-practices

Comment: I don't see any power supply decoupling capacitors, either.

Comment: I had a capacitor connected but that didn't do anything.

Comment: i do not see any data line connections .... the picture is unclear .... please include a schematic